# Formally speaking: why you cannot write a stream-reverse function for a Racket stream just like you can write one for lists?

Tags: stream, racket, reverse

Racket provides a built-in function to reverse lists which is called `reverse`. This function uses the fact that lists (at least proper lists) have an end which is `null` (empty list).

On the other hand, streams by definition **do not** have an end. Actually, streams is a data structure created exactly to model **infinite** data.

Hence, there is not such a way to build a stream-reverse function.

Is the argumentation above enough to answer the question?
Did I miss something?

It looks too informal for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can make infinite streams not all streams need to be infinite. Eg. `(stream 1 2 3 4)` will make a stream with delayed execution of the 4 elements and it is reversible.

You can make a `stream-reverse`, but it will not work for infinite lists just like `reverse` and `sort` doesn't work for circular lists, just proper lists.